# Trying to insert current date / ISODate() into MongoDB using RoboMongo

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am currently using RoboMongo to insert documents into my MongoDB collection.  At times, I also need to make updates as well.  My documents have two fields are causing me issues:

`createdDate` and `updateDate`

What I would like to do is provide the current Date and time stamp for when I make changes to the document, or when I insert a new document altogether.  Inside RoboMongo, I'm trying to do the following:

```
{
     createdDate: new Date(),
     updatedDate: new Date(),
}
```

I have also tried replacing "new Date()" with "ISODate()" but when I try either option, I get an error from RoboMongo saying that I have a particular error on a particular line (which is where I am trying to call the Date()/ISODate() function.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: What error at least? What query you make? The only solution that comes to mind for "a particular error on a particular line" is "a particular fix". Also, what version of Robomongo. They are Robo3T for quite long time already.

Comment: Thanks very much for responding.  I'm using Robo 3T 1.1, and the specific error message I get is: "Unable to parse JSON: Expecting '}' or ',', at (9, 30)."

Comment: Apparently the syntax of the query is wrong. Please update the question with reproducible query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$currentDate` for getting current date time in mongo Db

You can follow example given in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/)